# WP Query to get all posts (including in draft/pending review)

Tags: wp-query

I currently have the following query:

```
$args = array(
              'post_type' => 'post',
              'orderby'   => 'title',
              'order'     => 'ASC',
              'posts_per_page' => 10,
            );

$my_query = new WP_Query($args);

while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
```

This returns all the posts that are published. How can I alter it to show every post whether it's published, pending, or in draft?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can add post_status to your query, the string 'any' will return all posts no matter the status, or you can use an array to just grab those you want.

```
$args = array(
              'post_type' => 'post',
              'orderby'   => 'title',
              'order'     => 'ASC',
              'post_status' => 'any',
              'posts_per_page' => 10,
            );
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Status_Parameters

Answer (score 2):

Also you can customize for pending and drafts or any selected status

```
$args = array(
              'post_type' => 'post',
              'orderby'   => 'title',
              'order'     => 'ASC',
              'post_status' => array( 'pending', 'draft', 'future' ),
              'posts_per_page' => 10,
            );
```